# Letters in math font looks wrong

Tags: math-mode, miktex, math-fonts

I was trying to use `\usepackage{times}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}` for texts and equations. However, letters in Equations looks abnormal for some reason which I never experience before. What could be the reason? Example is attached below. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,   
    urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\begin{document}    
  $\boldsymbol{\dot{X}}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please give us a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? We don’t have enough information to duplicate the problem.

Comment: `\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 citecolor=blue,
 linkcolor=blue,   
 urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\begin{document}
 $\boldsymbol{\dot{X}}$
\end{document}` 
@Davislor

Comment: It’d be better-formatted if you edited this into your question. Would you mind doing that with a minimal document that compiles on TeX Live or MikTeX? At a guess, `kotex` loads Korean fonts and you might have one of those selected by mistake.

Comment: I see, Let me check if that is the case. However, I should not avoid using  `kotex`. 
Thank you @Davislor

Comment: Okay, after installing [`thesis.cls`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/thesis) and changing to `\documentclass[11pt]{thesis}`, I do not get this bug in TeX Live 2020. Perhaps upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I can’t duplicate your bug in TeX Live 2020.  The file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{    citecolor=blue,     linkcolor=blue,     urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\dot{X}}$
\end{document}
```

produces Nimbus Roman No9 as the font, which I assume is correct.  (I needed to download `thesis.cls` from CTAN.)  So you might try upgrading.

Alternatively, perhaps remove `\usepackage{mathptmx}` and load `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` after `kotex` and before `bm`, that is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{    citecolor=blue,     linkcolor=blue,     urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\dot{X}}$
\end{document}
```

The documentation for `mathptmx` warns that it is obsolete and you should use `newtx` instead.  The package might not be embedding all the fonts it uses, which could cause a PDF reader to display the wrong one.

Comment: Ok, I actually have updated miktex with Texstudio. Let me rearrange the packages as you suggested and see . Thank you

Comment: @HassenNigatu Make sure you have the latest versions of your packages installed, then.

Comment: Hmm..How do I know if some of the packages are obsoleted? Actually, the problem did not appear when I write manuscripts. It only occurs on this particular case, and `kotex` is not an issue. I checked it.

Comment: @HassenNigatu The log should tell you what versions you have installed. But I'd check if you’re loading them from the standard MikTeX tree, and check in the package manager that all your packages are updated.

Comment: @HassenNigatu What does `pdffonts` tell you is the math font you're using?

Comment: Actually there are several fonts. To mention few:
- CMEX10
- CMM10
- NimbusRomNo9
-StandardSyml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120528/discussion-between-davislor-and-hassen-nigatu).